# yii multiselect dropdown with search property?

Tags: php, yii

I want a searchable multiselect dropdown.I have seen yii multiselect and EchMultiselect extension but these are not according to my need. Please suggest any ext or code for this.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

dropdown Example - Same as stackoverflow uses for tags input.

Comment: What are your needs exactly?

Comment: I want a multiselect dropdown with search in yii.

Comment: @mamta Use `Select2` https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: @SiZE thanks for it but how to use it in my yii app?

Comment: And how we know what is your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**chosen**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin. It is also available as Yii extension, called [**chosen widget**](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/chosen-widget/)

Example of usage:

```
    //1st step is to make a list box with proper selector
    <?php echo CHtml::activeListBox($model, 'attribute', $data, array('class'=>'chosen', 'multiple'=>true, 'data-placeholder'=>'Select')) ?>

    //2nd step is use this widget
    <?php $this->widget('ext.chosen.EChosenWidget',array(
        'selector'=>'.chosen',
    )); ?>
```

It will do magic and convert normal multiple select to searchable multiple select. Of course there a lot of options, which are described in [chosen plugin documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).